# Finding a feasible solution subject to linear constraints and a column space constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

I'm trying to find a $n$-by-$m$ matrix $M$ that obeys the following constraints:

1) It is a conditional probability matrix,
$$
 M_{ij}\ge 0 \quad \forall i,j \qquad , \qquad \sum_j M_{ij} = 1 \quad \forall i
$$
2) It obeys the linear constraint
$$
\vec{a}^T M = 0
$$
3) It contains some vector $\vec{b}$ in its column space, i.e., 
$$ \exists \vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}^m\qquad \text{s.t.}\qquad  M \vec{x} = \vec{b}$$

In fact, I do not so much need the matrix $M$ itself as to know whether such a matrix exists, given some specified $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. In particular, I don't know how to deal with the column space constraint.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @YukiJ  Ubless $\vec{a} = $ zero vector, any solution $M$ of $M\vec{a} = 0$ must not be inveretible.